# C# WinForms Control on order changed event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application with a custom "tab" concept, in that there are 3 buttons that call their respective panels "BringToFront()" method.

As these panels are all initialised when the Form is initialised, but contain separate functionality of their own, I don't want to initialise some of the more intensive tasks until that Panel has been "switched" to.

For example, one of my Panels has a Twitter connection functionality. If I initialise the Twitter connection on the Panel initialisation, it may fail while in theory the user is on a completely different panel/functionality.

I only want it to try to connect to Twitter once the user has come to this panel.

So, I've been reading through MSDN but can't find an event that fires when a Controls display order has been changed.

I've come across these events, but not sure which/if at all, these work or are best:

`Panel.OnVisibleChanged
Panel.OnEnter
Panel.OnGotFocus`

I'm still learning C#, so any help/comments is appreciated.

Comment: For each panel keep a flag somewhere which shows if the panel is loaded. Create a method to switch to panels. In the method, check if the panel still is not loaded, then load it and set the flag and bring it to front.

Comment: This problem is a good example for back ground task. Once you feel current panel's properties are set, you can start initializing the other panels in background. Panel's tag property can be used to preserve a boolean value if its set or not. Moreover, you can hide and visible the panel's rather than BringToFront. This will fire the VisibleChanged event and easy to capture and process once they are visible.

Comment: As another option you can encapsulate content of panels in `UserControl` classes and then at first time which you click on a button, check if related panel is empty, then create an instance of the desired user control and add it to the panel. You can encapsulate the loading logic in Loading event of the user control.

Comment: You'll have to stop looking for an event for this, there isn't any.  The user can never do anything himself to alter the Z-order of controls, only your code can do that.  So the solution is very simple, just declare your own event and raise it in the same method(s) that calls BringToFront().  Using TabControl instead of cooking this up yourself is another simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by making each tab to implement an interface and trigering it whenever i try to load it (i hope that makes sense)(https://github.com/WithoutCaps/LimitlessUI/blob/master/LimitlessUI/TabsAdapter_WOC.cs)

lines 30/31

```
if(tab is Tab_WOC)
     ((Tab_WOC)tab).onShowTab();
```

feel free to use this code/library

NOTE: there is demo app too!

Comment: Thanks -- although I feel like the others probably offer a more robust "proper" way to do it in the end this is how I implemented it :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't use the Library just the methodology of using an Interface attached to all Panel classes that had a method which is called by a single method on click.

Comment: Im not sure are other awnsers are "proper" ones or "overcomplicated" onces, all i know that my way is simple and clean. Dont worry bout not using my library, its not big deal, afterall, im writing it mainly for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a good example for back ground task. Once you feel current panel's properties are set, you can start initializing the other panels in background. Panel's tag property can be used to preserve a boolean value if its set or not. Moreover, you can hide and show the panel's rather than BringToFront. This will fire the VisibleChanged event and easy to capture and process once they are visible.
This is to show you how background worker code will be.

```
private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Panel1.Tag)) {
            //Intialize panel1
            Panel1.Tag = true;
        }
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Panel2.Tag)) {
            //Intialize panel2
            Panel2.Tag = true;
        }
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Panel3.Tag)) {
            //Intialize panel3
            Panel3.Tag = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I do not know how you have your project laid out but I see two options.

**Option 1: Property that lazy loads**

Create a property that when you call it checks to see if a field is null and if it is, initialize it with a call to whatever expensive class constructor you want.

```
public TwitterCommunicator TwitterCommunicator => _twitterCommunicator ?? (_twitterCommunicator = new TwitterCommunicator());

public void AnotherTwitterPanelMethod()
{
    TwitterCommunicator.LoadTweets();
}
```

**Option 2: Use `Lazy<T>`**

Similar to lazy loading property. Actually use Lazy which provides lazy initialization of your object when you actually want it to initialize.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        Lazy<TwitterCommunicator> _lazyTwitter = new Lazy<TwitterCommunicator>();
    }
}

public void SomeTwitterPanelMethod()
{
    _lazyTwitter.Value.LoadTweets();
}
```